# Porting from Visual-Studio C++ project to gcc makefile

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, makefile

I need to port from Visual-Studio C++ project to gcc makefile.
The makefile should be built on Linux.

Is there an updated tool to do this porting?

Thanks for any tip

Comment: You just need include folder paths, library folder paths, library names, compiler flags and linker flags for starters. Then create makefile which will compile all source files following [online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: use CMake. Generate the visual studio projects first on Windows which is your known environment. Then generate makefiles on linux.

Comment: Thank you @TooTone, but how do I generate the CMake make-file from my Visual-Studio project file?

Comment: you don't. CMake generates build files, visual studio projects on windows, makefiles on linux (or ninja on both, etc). I think it would be easier to get a CMake project going that essentially replaces your windows build, and _then_ run that on linux. I wouldn't program makefiles directly, even if I only wanted to target linux.

Comment: ***Is there an updated tool to do this porting?*** Most likely you will have to do this yourself. I second the CMake recommendation. And what that means is spend a few hours learning CMake and create a CMakeLists.txt for your code and use it on Visual Studio. When that works attempt to use it under linux.

Comment: The short direct answer to your question is, as far as I'm aware there is no tool that can automatically translate a Visual Studio project file into any other format, not makefiles and not CMake files.  You will have to choose one and write it from scratch.

Comment: Over a decade ago there was a tool to convert visual studio projects into CMake however the CMakeLists.txt it produced was non friendly to modify so I had found out it was much easier to just spend the time and write your CMakeLists.txt from scratch.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the tool I used long ago or not but I found this software: [https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter](https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter)